# Getting the sum of select values to render on screen in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an app that renders 9 boxes each with 4 different select values.
Options of select are : close successful, close unsuccessful, callback, and open. I'm trying to find a way to count all closed successfully and all closed unsuccessfully and render the number on top of the screen.
What would be the best way to approach this? I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you very much.

Parent component BackGround.js (calling API , setting state and then maping over and rendering 9 card components.) :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Card from "./Card";

export default class Background extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      people: [],
    };
    this.handleRerender = this.handleRerender.bind(this);
  }

  async handleRerender() {
    let data = await axios
      .get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=9`)
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("Error ========> Fetching Failed Please reload page", error);
        this.handleRerender();
      });

    this.setState({
      people: data.data.results,
    });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let data = await axios
      .get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=9`)
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("Error ========> Fetching Failed", error);
        this.handleRerender();
      });

    this.setState({
      people: data.data.results,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const people = this.state.people.map((person) => {
      return (
        <Card
          key={person.cell}
          name={`${person.name.first}  ${person.name.last}`}
          email={person.email}
          phone={person.phone}
          company={person.location.city}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <>
        <div className='top'>
          <h1 className="title">XpressLeads</h1>
          <div className="btn">
            <button onClick={this.handleRerender}>Get new leads</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">{people}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Child Component Card.js (renders select boxes and some other props)

```
import React from "react";
import { CopyToClipboard } from "react-copy-to-clipboard";

class Card extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isEmailed: false,
    isCalled: false,
    copied: false,
    selectValue: "",
  };

  handleIsEmailedChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      isEmailed: !this.state.isEmailed,
    });
  };

  handleIsCalledChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      isCalled: !this.state.isCalled,
    });
  };

  handleCopy = () => {
    this.setState({
      copied: !this.state.copied,
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ copied: false });
    }, 1000);
  };

  handleDropdownChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selectValue: e.target.value });
  };

  handleCount = () => {
    const success = this.state.selectValue === "success";
    const fail = this.state.selectValue === "fail";
    const callback = this.state.selectValue === "callback";

    if (success) {
      return <p>success</p>;
    }
    if (fail) {
      return <p>fail</p>;
    }
    if (callback) {
      return <p>callback</p>;
    }
  };

  render() {
    const success = this.state.selectValue === "success";
    const fail = this.state.selectValue === "fail";
    const callback = this.state.selectValue === "callback";

    console.log(this.state.totalSuccess);
    return (
      <div
        className={
          success
            ? "box success"
            : fail
            ? "box fail"
            : callback
            ? "box callback"
            : "box"
        }
      >
        <div className="outcome">
          <ion-icon name="podium-outline"></ion-icon>
          <label htmlFor="outcome">Outcome {"  "}</label>
          <select name="outcome" onChange={this.handleDropdownChange}>
            <option value="open">open</option>
            <option value="success">close successful</option>
            <option value="fail">close unsuccessful</option>
            <option value="callback">callback </option>
          </select>
        </div>

        {this.handleCount()}

        <h4>
          <ion-icon name="people-circle-outline"></ion-icon>Name:{" "}
          {this.props.name}
        </h4>
        <h4>
          <ion-icon name="business-outline"></ion-icon>
          Company: {this.props.company}
        </h4>
        <h4>
          <ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
          Email: {"  "}
          <a className="link" href={`mailto:${this.props.email}`}>
            {this.props.email}
          </a>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.isEmailed}
            onChange={this.handleIsEmailedChange}
          />
          emailed
        </h4>

        <h4 className="number">
          <ion-icon name="call-outline"></ion-icon>Number: {this.props.phone}
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.isCalled}
            onChange={this.handleIsCalledChange}
          />
          called
          <CopyToClipboard text={this.props.phone}>
            <button className="copy-btn" onClick={this.handleCopy}>
              {this.state.copied ? "copied" : "copy"}
            </button>
          </CopyToClipboard>
        </h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want from the code you've provided. Theres a bunch of other code unrelated to the `<select>` stuff that could do with removing to make it easier for people to read/understand the specific issue you are wanting resolved. Possibly setting up 9 `<select>`'s and having them store in state would be a good start (in a codesandbox makes it even easier :) )

Comment: You're right I apologize. I added the full code with brief explanation. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Did you try counting in handleDropdownChange method ? Maybe something like this

```
handleDropdownChange = (e) => {
  let { successCount, unsuccessCount } = this.state;
  switch(e.target.value) {
    case 'success':
      successCount += 1;
      break;
    case 'fail':
      unsuccessCount += 1;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  this.setState({
    successCount: successCount,
    unsuccessCount: unsuccessCount,
    selectValue: e.target.value
  });
};
```

With *successCount*, *unsuccessCount* should be declared.

Comment: I like the idea.  I've tried your code and when i select success option it does add 1 to state but stays at 1. When I select the other boxes it always stays at 1 for some reason. I'd doesn't add the other values

Comment: setState does provide parameter that present the previous state to make change. You should use it to make count value increase everytime you set state. Checkout [this document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)